# DRF - how to validate url parameters

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I build API. In my url I can have `include` parameter where I can place names of relationships that should be included in the response together with main object. I would like to validate names in `include` to only allow the ones specified in serializer.

Where is the best place to validate these url parameters and at which point? In which method?

Comment: It would be helpful if you would provide your code.

Comment: try middleware to restrict. or say clearly